# Can not complie Jar in Unix by changing Java Version number

Tags: java, eclipse, unix

My Java code version in Unix is 1.5 but I have developed the jar in 1.5 version using eclipse.

I tried executing following command from unix, but fails .

```
javac -source 1.7 -target 1.5 -bootclasspath xml_test.jar
```

Refer : [How to run .jar file on unix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1333708/how-to-run-jar-file-on-unix)

**Log:**

> ```
> -bash-3.00$ javac -source 1.5 -target 1.5 -bootclasspath xmltest.jar
> javac: no source files
> Usage: javac <options> <source files>
> where possible options include:
>   -g Generate all debugging info
>   -g:none Generate no debugging info
>   -g:{lines,vars,source} Generate only some debugging info
>   -nowarn Generate no warnings
>   -verbose Output messages about what the compiler is doing
>   -deprecation Output source locations where deprecated APIs are used
>   -classpath <path> Specify where to find user class files
>   -cp <path> Specify where to find user class files
>   -sourcepath <path> Specify where to find input source files
>   -bootclasspath <path> Override location of bootstrap class files
>   -extdirs <dirs> Override location of installed extensions
>   -endorseddirs <dirs> Override location of endorsed standards path
>   -d <directory> Specify where to place generated class files
>   -encoding <encoding> Specify character encoding used by source files
>   -source <release> Provide source compatibility with specified release
>   -target <release> Generate class files for specific VM version
>   -version Version information
>   -help Print a synopsis of standard options
>   -X Print a synopsis of nonstandard options
>   -J<flag> Pass <flag> directly to the runtime system
> ```

Could you please suggest any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot compile a jar. A jar (Java ARchive)  file is a collection of java class files (and other resources) and thus, is already complied.

You can only compile .java source files.

Comment: Please refer this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1333708/how-to-run-jar-file-on-unix

Comment: That doesn't change the facts. You still cannot compile a jar. As explained in the accepted answer in that question, you need to either recompile your source code, to support an older target, or upgrade your unix JVM.

Comment: where to recompile ? in Unix or eclipse ?

Comment: It doesn't really matter. I'd recommend Eclipse, because it's somewhat more intuitive.

Answer (score 1):

What are you doing with a jar using javac? Execution is just java, javac is used to compile

Comment: changed to compile .. please check question

Comment: @logan You need to compile on the source files not on the already compiled java archive (jar).

Comment: Please refer this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1333708/how-to-run-jar-file-on-unix

Comment: @logan With compiling, you need the source code. -bootclasspath is referencing a jar in the JDK package that will be used to start the Java VM, not your already compiled jar. That question you referenced teach how to compile targeting a VM version. Use **javac -source 1.5 -target 1.5 -bootclasspath /path/to/jre1.5/lib/rt.jar <source file list>** to compile. *You should replace path/to/jre but not rt.jar*

Comment: you mean <source file list> is xml_test.jar ?

Comment: @logan No, you may not use a jar. Use your *.java files

Comment: how to run then , is it not possible to run latest of version jar in older version?

Comment: @logan Well as you said, your eclipse already compiled your java codes targeting Java 1.5, then it would be safe to use JVM newer that 1.5 to run your code directly.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44688/discussion-between-logan-and-twilightsun)